# New kext descriptions in Catalina

Tags: catalina, kernel-panic

I don't have a Mac that can run Catalina, so this is really more of an intellectual exercise..

From a couple of kernel panics I've seen posted on Ask Different recently, the style of the loaded kext list seems to have changed.

```
loaded kexts:
at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch   5430
@filesystems.msdosfs    1.10
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 4.5.9
```

from the older style I've been used to seeing for years

```
loaded kexts:
at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch   5208
com.symantec.SymXIPS    8.2.2
com.apple.filesystems.afpfs 11.1
```

<sup>These were picked pretty much at random from a couple of existing panic reports posted here</sup>

Is there an explanation for this change in presentation, from `domain.company.product` to `@` `>!` etc?
Is the fact that Little Snitch seems unchanged because it's third party, not Apple?

Here's a complete one from a recent post - utter gobbledygook… we could really do with some translation guidance.

```
loaded kexts:
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 4.7.2
@fileutil   20.036.15
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   4.7.2
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.3f5
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>pmtelemetry    1
>AGPM   111.4.2
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>!A!IBDWGraphics    14.0.4
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.3
>eficheck   1
>!AHDA  283.15
>!ABacklight    180.1
|Broadcom!B20703USBTransport    7.0.3f5
>!ASMCLMU   212
>!ALPC  3.1
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
>!ACameraInterface  7.6.0
>!AMCCSControl  1.13
>!A!IBDWGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.4
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!UCardReader   489.80.2
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.0.9
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.81.1
>!AAHCIPort 341.0.2
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!ARTC  2.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>!AGraphicsControl  4.7.2
|IOAVB!F    800.17
>!ASSE  1.0
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    810.1
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  569.4
@!AGPUWrangler  4.7.2
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   7.0.3f5
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.3f5
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.3f5
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    4.7.2
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.3.1
|IOGraphics!F   569.4
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
@kext.triggers  1.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOSurface  269.6
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
|IOAHCIBlock!S  316.80.1
|IOAHCI!F   290.0.1
>!AActuatorDriver   3430.1
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.5
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.5
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.3f5
|IO!B!F 7.0.3f5
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.3f5
>!AMultitouchDriver 3430.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3430.1
>!AHSSPIHIDDriver   59
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.0
>!AHSSPISupport 59
>!A!ILpssSpi!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.80.2
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.0.2
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOTimeSync!F   810.1
|IONetworking!F 3.4
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.40.7
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.0.2
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
```