# MacBook Pro keeps crashing [hardware issue?]

Tags: crash, error, restart

MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2018, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports) running on Version 10.15.2.

It happens a couple of times now this week. Is this a hardware issue? Should I just bring my MacBook pro to the store? The online chat with apple is not very helpful

```
Machine-check capabilities: 0x0000000000000c0b
 family: 6 model: 142 stepping: 10 microcode: 198
 signature: 0x806ea
 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8259U CPU @ 2.30GHz
 11 error-reporting banks
Processor 0: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0xba00000011000402
 IA32_MC4_MISC(0x413):   0x0000000000000000
Processor 1: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0xba00000011000402
 IA32_MC4_MISC(0x413):   0x0000000000000000
Processor 2: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0xba00000011000402
 IA32_MC4_MISC(0x413):   0x0000000000000000
Processor 3: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0xba00000011000402
 IA32_MC4_MISC(0x413):   0x0000000000000000
Processor 4: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0xba00000011000402
 IA32_MC4_MISC(0x413):   0x0000000000000000
Processor 5: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0xba00000011000402
 IA32_MC4_MISC(0x413):   0x0000000000000000
Processor 6: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0xba00000011000402
 IA32_MC4_MISC(0x413):   0x0000000000000000
Processor 7: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0xba00000011000402
 IA32_MC4_MISC(0x413):   0x0000000000000000
mp_kdp_enter() timed-out on cpu 3, NMI-ing
mp_kdp_enter() NMI pending on cpus: 0 1 2 4 5 6 7
mp_kdp_enter() timed-out during locked wait after NMI;expected 8 acks but received 1 after 9443842 loops in 1152000000 ticks
panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff8018065a3c): "Machine Check at 0x00007fff6fd7b4be, registers:\n" "CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x00000001043ff000, CR3: 0x00000003c57dd09a, CR4: 0x00000000003626e0\n" "RAX: 0x000000000000fe53, RBX: 0x00007f96bd875b40, RCX: 0x0000000000000000, RDX: 0x0000000000056d60\n" "RSP: 0x00007000045d02f0, RBP: 0x00007000045d0320, RSI: 0x0000000000000001, RDI: 0x00007f96be01bdc0\n" "R8:  0x000007f96bd82fbd, R9:  0x0000000000000003, R10: 0x00007f96bd800000, R11: 0x00007f96bd8a8150\n" "R12: 0x00007f96bd875b40, R13: 0x0000000000000000, R14: 0x0000000000000000, R15: 0x00007f96bcf0d5c0\n" "RFL: 0x0000000000000206, RIP: 0x00007fff6fd7b4be, CS:  0x000000000000002b, SS:  0x0000000000000023\n" "Error code: 0x0000000000000000\n"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-6153.61.1/osfmk/i386/trap_native.c:168
Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff922a76bbe0 : 0xffffff8017f3bb1b 
0xffffff922a76bc30 : 0xffffff80180733e5 
0xffffff922a76bc70 : 0xffffff8018064e5e 
0xffffff922a76bcc0 : 0xffffff8017ee2a40 
0xffffff922a76bce0 : 0xffffff8017f3b207 
0xffffff922a76bde0 : 0xffffff8017f3b5eb 
0xffffff922a76be30 : 0xffffff80186d24f9 
0xffffff922a76bea0 : 0xffffff8018065a3c 
0xffffff922a76bf90 : 0xffffff80186d2678 
0xffffff922a76bfa0 : 0xffffff8017ee329f 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: accountsd
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
19C57

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.2.0: Sat Nov  9 03:47:04 PST 2019; root:xnu-6153.61.1~20/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: C3E7E405-C692-356B-88D3-C30041FD1E72
Kernel slide:     0x0000000017c00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8017e00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8017d00000
System model name: MacBookPro15,2 (Mac-827FB448E656EC26)
System shutdown begun: NO

System uptime in nanoseconds: 85400514352429
last loaded kext at 77102180642164: >usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2 (addr 0xffffff7f9c030000, size 45056)
last unloaded kext at 71166797937316: >!UAudio  320.49 (addr 0xffffff7f9c2a2000, size 434176)
loaded kexts:
com.google.drivefs.filesystems.dfsfuse  35.0.13
@filesystems.smbfs  3.4
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 4.5.21
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   4.5.21
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.2f4
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>AGPM   111.4.1
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>pmtelemetry    1
>!A!IKBLGraphics    14.0.3
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.3
>BridgeAudioCommunication   6.60
>!ABacklight    180.1
>!ABridgeAudio!C    6.60
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.422
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3420.1
>!AHIDALSService    1
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.3
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
>!AMCCSControl  1.13
@fileutil   20.036.15
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>usb.!UHostBillboardDevice  1.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.61.1
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.0.9
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!AVirtIO   1.0
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe  1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>!UAudio    320.49
>usb.cdc.acm    5.0.0
>usb.serial 6.0.0
>usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
>!UMergeNub 900.4.2
>!AGraphicsControl  4.5.21
|IOAVB!F    800.17
>!ASSE  1.0
@!AGPUWrangler  4.5.21
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
>!AActuatorDriver   3420.2
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
|IONDRVSupport  569.3
>!AHS!BDriver   3420.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.2f4
>!AMultitouchDriver 3420.2
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3420.4
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    7.0.2f4
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.2f4
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    4.5.21
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.2.8
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IOGraphics!F   569.3
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    800.14
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
@kext.triggers  1.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.2
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.4
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.4
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
|IOSurface  269.6
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.1
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.4.7
>!ABCMWLANCore  1.0.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IO80211!FV2    1200.12.2b1
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.60.3
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.0.2
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
|IOTimeSync!F   800.14
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 7.0.2f4
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.2f4
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.40.7
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.0.2
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1
```

Comment: Have you tried starting in Safe Mode or running the Apple Hardware diagnostics?  Any of those sorts of things?

Comment: You can install a clean version of macOS to a USB drive (spinning or flash) and boot from that.  If it’s not stable there, you’ve got your answer.

Comment: If anybody's figured out how to read these new kext lists yet, drop me a line - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375058/new-kext-descriptions-in-catalina