# Why is my kernel panic report formatted incorrectly?

Tags: catalina, kernel-panic

Usually kernel panic reports are formatted correctly. Mine are being output in a long stream of text with control characters inside the body of the text, like `\n` for newline and `\t` for tab. Actually here when posting the text inside code block it looks better than inside console or when I use `cat` in terminal because it's not being wrapped here.

What might be the cause of this - how it's output or how it's read?
Or is this the new format on Catalina?

In the meantime is there a `sed` command that will work to replace all instances of '\n' with a real newline and all instances of '\t' with a real tab?

```
{"timestamp":"2022-01-31 08:19:01.70 -0600","bug_type":"210","os_version":"Mac OS X 10.15.7 (19H1713)"}
{"macOSProcessedStackshotData":"bm8gb24gZGlzayBvciBzbGVlcC93YWtlIGZhaWx1cmUgcGFuaWMgc3RhY2tzaG90IGZvdW5k","macOSPanicString":"panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff7f8e0acaae): watchdog timeout: no checkins from watchdogd in 301 seconds (23409 totalcheckins since monitoring last enabled), shutdown in progress\nBacktrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address\n0xffffff8745cbbc40 : 0xffffff800d31c54d \n0xffffff8745cbbc90 : 0xffffff800d456c85 \n0xffffff8745cbbcd0 : 0xffffff800d44880e \n0xffffff8745cbbd20 : 0xffffff800d2c2a40 \n0xffffff8745cbbd40 : 0xffffff800d31bc17 \n0xffffff8745cbbe40 : 0xffffff800d31c007 \n0xffffff8745cbbe90 : 0xffffff800dac0b58 \n0xffffff8745cbbf00 : 0xffffff7f8e0acaae \n0xffffff8745cbbf10 : 0xffffff7f8e0ac486 \n0xffffff8745cbbf50 : 0xffffff7f8e100d9c \n0xffffff8745cbbfa0 : 0xffffff800d2c213e \n      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:\n         com.apple.driver.watchdog(1.0)[BEE4EBAA-0E64-3CB0-AA33-B8A48B6E080D]@0xffffff7f8e0ab000->0xffffff7f8e0b3fff\n         com.apple.driver.AppleSMC(3.1.9)[BC761D0D-ABA0-3E48-A55A-6F32B7D359CF]@0xffffff7f8e0f3000->0xffffff7f8e111fff\n            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[B5C80E7A-0488-3909-A5B3-9CE7533AB7E6]@0xffffff7f8e0a2000\n            dependency: com.apple.driver.watchdog(1)[BEE4EBAA-0E64-3CB0-AA33-B8A48B6E080D]@0xffffff7f8e0ab000\n            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[E20147A5-BD1C-3D7E-82D6-58B02C679346]@0xffffff7f8e0b4000\n\nBSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task\n\nMac OS version:\n19H1713\n\nKernel version:\nDarwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Thu Jan 13 01:26:33 PST 2022; root:xnu-6153.141.51~3\/RELEASE_X86_64\nKernel UUID: 5977F3A2-F5FD-347E-8711-46F16CE0993B\nKernel slide:     0x000000000d000000\nKernel text base: 0xffffff800d200000\n__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800d100000\nSystem model name: iMac19,1 (Mac-AA95B1DDAB278B95)\nSystem shutdown begun: YES\nPanic diags file available: NO (0xe00002bc)\n\nSystem uptime in nanoseconds: 234380979617206\nlast loaded kext at 15010083080: >!AHIDKeyboard\t209 (addr 0xffffff7f9056a000, size 45056)\nloaded kexts:\norg.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp\t6.1.32\norg.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt\t6.1.32\norg.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB\t6.1.32\norg.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv\t6.1.32\ncom.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower\t2\ncom.softraid.driver.SoftRAID\t6.2\n>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver\t3430.1\n|IOUSBAttachedSCSI\t1.1.6\n@fileutil\t20.036.15\n>!APlatformEnabler\t2.7.0d0\n>AGPM\t111.4.4\n>X86PlatformShim\t1.0.0\n@filesystems.autofs\t3.0\n>!AUpstreamUserClient\t3.6.8\n@kext.AMDFramebuffer\t3.1.0\n@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager\t3.1.0\n>AudioAUUC\t1.70\n>!AHDAHardwareConfigDriver\t283.15\n@kext.AMDRadeonX4000\t3.1.0\n>!AHDA\t283.15\n>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy\t5.2.7\n@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics\t5.2.7\n>!A!IKBLGraphics\t14.0.7\n@kext.AMD9500!C\t3.1.0\n>!AHV\t1\n>!ASMCLMU\t212\n>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer\t14.0.7\n|IOUserEthernet\t1.0.1\n|IO!BSerialManager\t7.0.6f8\n>!AThunderboltIP\t3.1.4\n>pmtelemetry\t1\n@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X\t7.0.0\n>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking\t4.0.0\n>!AFIVRDriver\t4.1.0\n>ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin\t1.0.0\n>eficheck\t1\n>!A!IPCHPMC\t2.0.1\n>AGDCBacklightControl\t5.2.7\n>!AGFXHDA\t100.1.429\n>!ABacklight\t180.3\n>!AMCCSControl\t1.14\n>Core!SFsck\t551.0.1\n|SCSITaskUserClient\t422.120.3\n>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore\t1\n>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore\t1\n>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore\t1\n>!AFileSystemDriver\t3.0.1\n>!AVirtIO\t1.0\n@filesystems.hfs.kext\t522.100.5\n@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless\t1.0.0d1\n@BootCache\t40\n@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib\t1.0.0\n>!ASDXC\t1.7.7\n|!ABCM5701Ethernet\t10.3.5\n>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe\t1\n@filesystems.apfs\t1412.141.2\n>!AAHCIPort\t341.140.1\n@private.KextAudit\t1.0\n>!AACPIButtons\t6.1\n>!ARTC\t2.0\n>!ASMBIOS\t2.1\n>!AACPIEC\t6.1\n>!AAPIC\t1.7\n$!AImage4\t1\n@nke.applicationfirewall\t303\n$TMSafetyNet\t8\n@!ASystemPolicy\t2.0.0\n|EndpointSecurity\t1\n>!AHIDKeyboard\t209\n>!AMultitouchDriver\t3440.1\n>!AInputDeviceSupport\t3440.8\n>!AHS!BDriver\t3430.1\n>IO!BHIDDriver\t7.0.6f8\n|IOUSBUserClient\t900.4.2\n@kext.triggers\t1.0\n@kext.AMDRadeonX4400HWLibs\t1.0\n@kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices\t3.1.0\n>DspFuncLib\t283.15\n@kext.OSvKernDSPLib\t529\n>!AGraphicsControl\t5.2.7\n|IOAVB!F\t850.1\n@kext.AMDSupport\t3.1.0\n|IOAccelerator!F2\t438.7.4\n>!AThunderboltEDMSink\t4.2.3\n>!ASMBusPCI\t1.0.14d1\n@!AGPUWrangler\t5.2.7\n|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F\t1.0.0\n|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport\t7.0.6f8\n|IO!BHost!CTransport\t7.0.6f8\n|IO!B!F\t7.0.6f8\n|IO!BPacketLogger\t7.0.6f8\n>IOPlatformPluginLegacy\t1.0.0\n>X86PlatformPlugin\t1.0.0\n>!A!ILpssUARTv1\t3.0.60\n>!A!ILpssUARTCommon\t3.0.60\n>!AOnboardSerial\t1.0\n>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice\t1.2\n>!AHDA!C\t283.15\n|IOHDA!F\t283.15\n>IOPlatformPlugin!F\t6.0.0d8\n@!AGraphicsDeviceControl\t5.2.7\n>!ABacklightExpert\t1.1.0\n|IONDRVSupport\t576.2\n>!ASMBus!C\t1.0.18d1\n|IOGraphics!F\t576.2\n@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin\t840.3\n>Core!S\t551.0.1\n>usb.!UHub\t1.2\n>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter\t6.2.6\n>!AThunderboltPCIUpAdapter\t2.5.4\n>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter\t6.2.6\n>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F\t6.2.6\n>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter\t2.5.4\n>!AHPM\t3.4.4\n>!A!ILpssI2C!C\t3.0.60\n>!A!ILpssDmac\t3.0.60\n>!A!ILpssI2C\t3.0.60\n>usb.cdc\t5.0.0\n>usb.networking\t5.0.0\n>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice\t1.2\n|IOAudio!F\t300.2\n@vecLib.kext\t1.2.0\n|IOSurface\t269.11\n@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext\t1\n|IOAHCIBlock!S\t316.100.5\n>!AThunderboltNHI\t5.8.6\n|IOThunderbolt!F\t7.6.1\n|IOEthernetAVB!C\t1.1.0\n>!ABCMWLANCore\t1.0.0\n>mDNSOffloadUserClient\t1.0.1b8\n>IOImageLoader\t1.0.0\n|IOSerial!F\t11\n|IO80211!FV2\t1200.12.2b1\n>corecapture\t1.0.4\n|IOSkywalk!F\t1\n>!AXsanScheme\t3\n|IONVMe!F\t2.1.0\n|IOAHCI!F\t290.0.1\n>usb.!UXHCIPCI\t1.2\n>usb.!UXHCI\t1.2\n>usb.!UHostPacketFilter\t1.0\n|IOUSB!F\t900.4.2\n>!AEFINVRAM\t2.1\n>!ASMCRTC\t1.0\n>!AEFIRuntime\t2.1\n|IOSMBus!F\t1.1\n|IOHID!F\t2.0.0\n$quarantine\t4\n$sandbox\t300.0\n@kext.!AMatch\t1.0.0d1\n>DiskImages\t493.0.0\n>!AFDEKeyStore\t28.30\n>!AEffaceable!S\t1.0\n>!ASSE\t1.0\n>!AKeyStore\t2\n>!UTDM\t489.120.1\n|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice\t422.120.3\n>!ACredentialManager\t1.0\n>KernelRelayHost\t1\n>!ASEPManager\t1.0.1\n>IOSlaveProcessor\t1\n|IOUSBMass!SDriver\t157.140.1\n|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F\t422.120.3\n|IO!S!F\t2.1\n|IOUSBHost!F\t1.2\n>!UHostMergeProperties\t1.2\n>usb.!UCommon\t1.0\n>!ABusPower!C\t1.0\n|CoreAnalytics!F\t1\n>!AMobileFileIntegrity\t1.0.5\n@kext.CoreTrust\t1\n|IOTimeSync!F\t840.3\n|IONetworking!F\t3.4\n|IOReport!F\t47\n>!AACPIPlatform\t6.1\n>!ASMC\t3.1.9\n>watchdog\t1\n|IOPCI!F\t2.9\n|IOACPI!F\t1.4\n@kec.pthread\t1\n@kec.corecrypto\t1.0\n@kec.Libm\t1\n\n\n"}
```

### EDIT - found temporary solution for formatting issue.

When replacing a literal **\n** with a newline on macOS you need to actually start a newline in the `sed` substitute command. Replacing **\t** with tab is just as tricky. You have to type "control-v" first then hit the tab key to enter a literal tab. The result of this is a readable kernel crash report.

```
john@iMac191 ~ % cat "/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Kernel_2022-01-31-081901_iMac191.panic" | sed 's/\\n/\
/g; s/\\t/      /g'> /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Kernel_2022-01-31-081901_iMac191-corrected.panic
```

Comparison of the two files: 
[original panic report](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/fz9x7s5oyxtk7bu/Kernel_2022-01-31-081901_iMac191.panic?) 
[corrected panic report](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/zeln9qveasjgiue/Kernel_2022-01-31-081901_iMac191-corrected.panic?)

Comment: They changed the format - I've no idea why - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375058/new-kext-descriptions-in-catalina - received no answers or comments so I assume no-one else did either.

Comment: @Tetsujin the link you shared is a different concern. My text is not wrapped or tabbed. The control characters are inline - in the string instead of being used to control the flow of the text.

Comment: Where is it displaying like this?

Comment: When I open the .panic report in console or run `cat` from terminal or open it in a text editor. I added the difference between the two, a before and after `sed` version.

Comment: It looks like this might happen if it doesn't have time to output properly. Not sure if it's relevant but I am seeing this inside the .panic file `Panic diags file available: NO (0xe00002bc)`

Comment: That's just a JSON file.